# What's the function of this "as"?

Tags: grammar

In http://lareviewofbooks.org/review/what-exactly-is-piracy/

> Spoo avoids rehashing the labyrinthine history of the work’s publication **except as** it bears upon his larger point.

What is the function of "as" in *except as*?

Answer (score 1):

In this context I would argue that it is short for 'except in so far as' ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of *as* is “to the extent, degree, or quantity of”; for instance:

> The soup was salty as seawater

means that it was salty the degree of seawater's saltiness, or to the same extent that seawater is salty.

You can therefore also rephrase the following sentence:

> Spoo rehashes the labyrinthine history ... to the extent that it bears upon his larger point.

as:

> Spoo rehashes the labyrinthine history ... as it bears upon his larger point.

This means that he doesn’t present the whole history, only the parts relevant to his case.  Note, though, that the second version is ambiguous, as *as* can also mean “because”.  Use of *only* or (with an explicitly or implicitly negative verb) *except* strongly forces *as* to be read with the meaning “to the extent that”:

> Spoo rehashes the labyrinthine history ... *only* as it bears upon his larger point.
>
> Spoo avoids rehashing the labyrinthine history of the work’s publication *except* as it bears upon his larger point.

The first of these two still (marginally?) allows a “because” reading, which you can kill off entirely with *insofar as*.  This is what @WS2 points out.  I don’t know why his/her answer got downvoted (I just upvoted it) and I hope that this spells out the same basic idea in more detail.

Comment: So this "as" is the same as "the world as we know it?"

Comment: Well, you can’t paraphrase _the world as we know it_ as _the world to the extent that / insofar as we know it_.  So, they’re not identical.  Rather, this _as_ is similar to _such as_ or _how_: _the world how / such as we know it_.  Note also that the two _as_’s are syntactically different.  You can say _This is as we know it_ with approximately the same meaning, but this is not the case with _This is as it bears on his larger point_.

Comment: No problem.  You can upvote responses or designate them as your choice answer if they've done what you want them to.  Cheers

Comment: I think you are wrong on this one. This "as" has a very special usage. It works like a relative pronoun but not so in its grammatical function. So in this case, "history as it related to his larger point."

Comment: Perhaps you could expand a bit.  A _relative pronoun_ is simply an item with a particular grammatical function.  So, it isn’t obvious what it means that _as_ “works like a relative pronoun but not so in its grammatical function”.  Or maybe you can articulate what’s “very special” about this usage of _as_?

Comment: the mountain as it was seen from the moon...this as is what I am talking about here.